# What is the difference between definitions of open set and saturated set?

Tags: general-topology

In a book, I have the following definition:
*A subset S of a topological space $\displaystyle ( X,\ T)$ is said to be saturated if it is an intersection of open sets in $\displaystyle ( X,\ T)$.*

I believe the author really meant not "if it is an intersection...", but "if and only if it is an intersection...", because this is a definition.

It seemed to me that "saturated" is same as "open", so I tried to prove it with the following.

Let $\displaystyle ( X,\ T)$ - a top. space, and let $\displaystyle S\subseteq X$. Prove: $\displaystyle ( S\ is\ open) \leftrightarrow ( S\ is\ saturated)$.

1. Assume $\displaystyle S\in T$. $\displaystyle S=S\cap S$ - an intersection of open sets. Hence, $\displaystyle S$ is saturated.
2. Assume $\displaystyle S$ is saturated. By definition of "saturated", it is an intersection of open sets, and therefore by definition of topological space, $\displaystyle S$ is an open set.

Am I missing something? Is "saturated" just a synonym for "open"?

Comment: Can you prove "If A subset S of a topological space (X, T) is said to be saturated", then it is an intersection of open sets in (X, T)."?  That needs to be proven to claim if and only if.

Comment: If $X$ is $T_1$, **all** subsets are saturated.

Comment: Regarding "if and only if": It's standard to use just "if" in expressing definitions like this; it's the normal English word "if", rather than the logical connective of implication. In fact, I've even seen it argued that it's *wrong* to use the mathematical "if and only if" in this sort of context, because using a logical connective presupposes that both statements are already well-defined. (Compare something like "A subset [...] is not said to be saturated unless [...]"; which is clearly a nonsensical way to present a definition!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not a synonym.  For instance, in $\Bbb R$, endowed with the usual topology, the set $\{0\}$ is not an open set, but it is saturated, since$$\{0\}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right).$$Note that, in a topological space, an arbitrary intersection of open sets doesn't have to be open.

Comment: yes, only finite intersections of open sets give open sets, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.